# Simple batch file issue

Tags: python, batch-file

So I have a really simple question, and I can't seem to find a really simple answer.

I have a batch file to run my code. This is what's in the batch file:

```
c:\python27\python.exe filename.py
pause
```

I want to run this batch file from a different directory than `filename.py` is in. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
c:\python27\python.exe filename.py
```

You need to give a full path to filename.py such as

```
c:\python27\python.exe C:\Users\username\Desktop\filename.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to give the full path to the filename as @AbhijeetRastogi said, or you can change your working directory and just use the filename.py as is. To use his example:

```
pushd C:\Users\username\Desktop\
c:\python27\python.exe filename.py
popd
pause
```

Per PA's suggestion, I've changed `cd` to `pushd/popd`. The difference is that now when the batch file runs, it will go back to where the current working directory was, instead of being in the path where `filename.py` is

Comment: you might find more useful to use `pushd` and `popd`.

Comment: and another difference is that `pushd` allows you to specify the drive.

Answer (score 0):

create a .cmd file containing the following command

```
Start "" /D "c:\Directory_of_your_py_file\" c:\python27\python.exe filename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
From the desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
```

highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you wish the computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a semicolon as shown below.

```
C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32;c:\python27\python.exe
```

then you should be able to type python.exe filename.py and it will find python and execute the file no matter what directory you are in.

Comment: I may be wrong (cause I just woke up), but I think it only searches the path env var for binary executables. so it would not find filename.py.